# Determinar el menor valor en una lista de diccionarios

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, diccionarios

Quiero determinar el menor valor de esta lista que contiene un diccionario:

```
data= [{'page_rank': 3387, 'code': 'SV'}, {'page_rank': 4022, 'code': 'NI'}, 
    {'page_rank': 5000, 'code': 'ES'}, {'page_rank': 4802, 'code': 'OC'}]
```

el mínimo  seria: `3387`, que representa a code `sv`, intenté hacerlo con la función `min(data)`, pero lo calcula por cada diccionario.

Comment: Si con menor valor te refieres al valor mínimo para la clave  `'page_rank'` es tan simple como `min(d['page_rank'] for d in data)`

Comment: Gracias FJSevilla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es obtener el diccionario cuyo valor sea el menor:

```
print(min(data, key=lambda x: x['page_rank']))

{'page_rank': 3387, 'code': 'SV'}
```

Si solo importa el valor, una ligera adaptación:

```
print(min(data, key=lambda x: x['page_rank'])['page_rank'])

3387
```

La función [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) permite establecer el parámetro `key` el cual sirve para indicarle de que forma obtener o cual sería el valor por el cual se calculará el mínimo. En este caso usamos una función anónima `lambda x: x['page_rank']` para retornar el valor indicado de cada clave `page_rank` del diccionario.

Comment: Muchas gracias, realmente lo que quería

Answer (score 4):

Si solo buscas el valor de la clave y no te importa el diccionario donde está, `min` junto a un generador es eficiente, simple y legible:

```
>>> min(d['page_rank'] for d in data)
3387
```

Si quieres también saber el diccionario en el que está o necesitas más eficiencia porque trabajes con una lista enorme de elementos, entonces posiblemente la mejor opción es usar el argumento `key` junto a `operator.itemgetter`:

```
>>> import operator

>>> data= [{'page_rank': 3387, 'code': 'SV'},
           {'page_rank': 4022, 'code': 'NI'}, 
           {'page_rank': 5000, 'code': 'ES'},
           {'page_rank': 4802, 'code': 'OC'}
           ]

>>> min(data, key=operator.itemgetter("page_rank"))
{'page_rank': 3387, 'code': 'SV'}
```

o si quieres el elemento solo o otra clave del diccionario:

```
>>> min(data, key=operator.itemgetter("page_rank"))["page_rank"]
3387

>>> min(data, key=operator.itemgetter("page_rank"))['code']
    'SV'
```

Aunque `operator.itemgetter` en general es más eficiente que el uso de funciones Python, lambda como muestra PatricioMoracho en su respuesta o normales, para listas relativamente pequeñas sin que sea una operación repetitiva la diferencia no es muy significativa y no debes preocuparte, suele ser más cuestión de gustos, de que consideres más legible o que estilo siga tu equipo. Para listas enormes u otros casos particulares, mantener las operaciones a nivel de C como consigues mediante `itemgetter` si que conlleva una diferencia a tener en cuenta. Una ventaja de `itemgetter` es que es serializable vía Pickle por lo que se puede usar sin problemas en multi-hilo/multi-proceso.